# Get app signature hash code in jni

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native

i want to get app signature in native with these code: ([source](http://www.programering.com/a/MjN4QzNwATc.html))

```
// For class Context
    jclass native_clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, context);

    // Get the getPackageManager method ID
    jmethodID methodID_func = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, native_clazz,
            "getPackageManager", "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");

    // Access manager application package
    jobject package_manager = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, thiz, methodID_func);

    // For class PackageManager
    jclass pm_clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, package_manager);

    // Get the getPackageInfo method ID
    jmethodID methodID_pm = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, pm_clazz,
            "getPackageInfo", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;");

    // To obtain the application package information
    jobject package_info = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, package_manager,
            methodID_pm, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "com.example.hellojni"), 64);
```

but i got this:

```
error: 'context' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

how do i get context in native? 
how do i return signature hashcode as string?

Comment: _"how do i get context in native?"_ You need to pass it (i.e. an `Activity` or `Application` instance) from your Java code to your C code.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the context to JNI in a parameter for example

```
jstring Java_packagename_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz , jobject context)
```

And when you call the method in your activity:

```
public native String stringFromJNI(Context context);
```

...

```
Log.d(TAG, "Receive: " + stringFromJNI(this));
```